# How to get the text output of a get request in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

```
from seleniumrequests import Firefox

webdriver = Firefox()
response = webdriver.get('https://www.google.com/').text
print(response)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "srequests.py", line 4, in <module>
    response = webdriver.get('https://www.google.com/').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

How do I print the get request text in my terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")

html = driver.page_source
```